# Why does GDAL Polygonize flip features vertically?

Tags: gdal, c++

I am trying to convert a 1 band jpg raster into polygons. 
It is converting the data and I get a polygon shape file. However, the output data is vertically flipped.
Input data have no reference system.

I am using the code in c++.

Comment: Please provide the code you used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a CRS to the source data with gdal_translate or another way.

The jpg raster has usually pixel coordinates from top left to the right and down, while GIS data like shapefiles have a coordinate system to the right and upwards.

If your input data has a CRS, the output can have the same CRS, and both will align.

Comment: Hi. My input raster is without reference and projection. I however, read the input raster's CRS using input raster dataset GetProjectionRef() and assigned to the our dataset to create the layer poDstDS->CreateLayer that was used for polygonizing. Even in this case, I have the problem.

Comment: I believe that the default geotransform makes the issue. Try to change is as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726637/how-do-i-change-a-rasters-geotransform-with-gdal into `# try to alter the geotransform and ensure that it has been set
dataset.SetGeoTransform([0,1,0,0,0,-1])`and test if it helps.